# Sorting ip address in an application

Tags: php, sorting

I've built an application where IP address can't be sorted out. I am using object oriented PHP. All the ip address value has been saved as varchar and when I sort that out, it looks like this:

```
192.168.111.1>192.168.111.100>192.168.111.101>....>192.168.111.2>192.168.111.200>...>192.168.111.3>192.168.111.300>.......
```

but the sorting should be like this:

```
192.168.111.1>192.168.111.2>192.168.111.3>....>192.168.111.99>192.168.111.100>.....192.168.111.300
```

I don't know how do I sort it out, could anybody help me out? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please paste your sorting code

Comment: You need to use a natural sort so that it sorts the components numerically.

Comment: You are comparing it as a string not numbers. Easy way would be to translate those strings to integers and then sort them

Answer (score 5):

Try natural ordering: `natsort`

```
$array = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.102', '192.168.1.3'];
natsort($array);
echo "\nNatural order sorting\n";
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Nice, I thought you'd have to mess with leading zero's but this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Waaay late to the party, but recently I needed something similar with a twist (my IP addresses were as the array's index, ksort() would not collaborate beyond the 2st octet)... and the solution might come in handy to someone else. I leveraged the `ip2long()` and `long2ip()` functions, like:

```
$array = [ '192.168.200.200', '192.168.10.10', '172.16.5.5', '172.16.20.20' ];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) $array[$key] = ip2long($value);
sort($array);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) $array[$key] = long2ip($value);
print_r($array);

Array
(
    [0] => 172.16.5.5
    [1] => 172.16.20.20
    [2] => 192.168.10.10
    [3] => 192.168.200.200
)
```